# Group By Object Property

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of `Inventory`:

```
class Inventory {
    String refCode;
    int min;
    int max;
    // getters and setters
}
```

```
refCode     min   max
-------    ----  ---
DOUBLE      2   2   
DOUBLE      2   2   
TWIN        1   2   
SINGLE      3   4
```

Now I wanted to group by using `min` property so that my output would be like this:

```
Map<String, int> output;

{DOUBLE=2, TWIN=1, SINGLE=3}
```

Comment: I don't want to sum min, and just need ref code and min value in map. Don't want max and sum it too.

Comment: What if there was an `Inventory` such as `TRIPLE  2  2`, how would that change your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to achieve this:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Inventory::getRefCode, Inventory::getMin, (a, b) -> a));
```

This keeps the first value if you have multiple keys. If you want to keep the last one just use `(a, b) -> b` instead of `(a, b) -> a`.

If you need the items to be in the same order as the list just use a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Inventory::getRefCode, Inventory::getMin, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```